# Как выбранный option из SELECT положить в сессию через AJAX? PHP AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

На странице из БД берутся данные и циклом отрисовывает option для выпадающего списка.

**Вопрос:** Как выбранный option из SELECT положить в сессию через AJAX методом POST?

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label pl-5">Цех заказчик:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <?php
# Выбрать из базы список цехов
    $querry_cex_zakazchik = "SELECT * FROM `cex` WHERE nomer_cex < 200"; // выбрать цеха, где номер цеха равен меньше 200
    $result_cex_zakazchik= mysqli_query($link_mysql, $querry_cex_zakazchik); // выполнить запрос
?>
      <select name="cex_z" class="form-control" placeholder="Выберите цех" autofocus size="1">
        <option value="0">Укажите цех</OPTION>
        <?php 
    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_cex_zakazchik)) {
            // в value $row['nomer_cex'] помещается значение из БД
            echo '<option value="'.$row['nomer_cex'].'">'. $row['nomer_cex'] . " - " . $row['name_cex'] . '</option>'; 
            // конец вывода на форму
            
        }
    ?>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery подключен к странице, но разобраться с AJAX не могу.

Comment: "Выбрать option из select" это один вопрос. "разобраться с AJAX" - это вообще не вопрос. "Положить в сессию" - это третий вопрос.

Comment: Старайтесь всегда делить задачу на более мелкие. Сначала получите нужное значение, и выведите его в консоль. Потом найдите примеры с AJAX и воспроизведите их у себя как есть, чтобы разобраться, как он работает. И только потом пробуйте добавить аякс к своему коду.

Comment: **Переформулировала Вопрос:** Как выбранный option из SELECT положить в сессию через AJAX методом POST?

Comment: Я вам только что сказал что это не один "вопрос", а **три**. Сделайте одолжение, прочитайте мой комментарий выше

Comment: Причем на **каждый** из них на этом сайте есть **сотни**  готовых ответов.